# Clojure idiomatic and memory-efficient loop

Tags: memory, clojure, lisp, idioms

I'm implementing a simple algorithm in Clojure that insists on blowing the memory, even with `:jvm-opts ["-Xmx4G"]` set on my `project.clj`. assuming the following data structures:

```
(def inf Double/POSITIVE_INFINITY)
(def min-dist (atom {:1 {:1 0 :2 4} :2 {:1 4 :2 0 :3 5} :3 {:2 5 :3 0}}))
(def vertexes [:1 :2 :3])
```

The following will run out of memory on bigger inputs (`|vertexes| = 100`):

```
(for [k vertexes i vertexes j vertexes]
  (do
    (println " " i " " j " "k)
    (let [s (+ (get-in @min-dist [i k] inf) (get-in @min-dist [k j] inf))]
      (if (> (get-in @min-dist [i j] inf) s) (swap! min-dist assoc-in [i j] s)))))
```

output:

```
OutOfMemoryError Java heap space  java.util.Arrays.copyOf (Arrays.java:2367)
```

I'm pretty sure that that is a `reduce` option here that will make everything clean and fast, but I just can't find it. It looks like `swap!`takes a lot of memory space, am I right?

---

Two bonus questions:

1. if I remove the `println` line (as well as the do, of course), the code will run fast, but `min-dist` will not be updated, as if the loops were not executed. Why is it?
2. The same behavior is seen when running with `lein run`, even with the `println` in there. Why?

Any help to a new Clojurist will be appreciated. =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

your sub question #1 is the key.

`for` produces a *lazy* list so no work is done unless the result is actually read. if you want the result to be evaluated you could wrap the whole thing in a call to `dorun` which traverses the list without keeping the whole thing in memory. I refer to this situation in general as "being bitten by the lazy bug" and it happens to most Clojurians more often than they let on ;-)

```
user> @min-dist
{:1 {:1 0, :2 4}, :2 {:1 4, :2 0, :3 5}, :3 {:2 5, :3 0}}
user> (time
        (dorun (for [k vertexes i vertexes j vertexes]
                 (let [s (+ (get-in @min-dist [i k] inf) (get-in @min-dist [k j] inf))]
                  (if (> (get-in @min-dist [i j] inf) s) (swap! min-dist assoc-in [i j] s))))))
"Elapsed time: 4.272336 msecs"
nil
user> @min-dist
{:1 {:1 0, :2 4, :3 9}, :2 {:1 4, :2 0, :3 5}, :3 {:2 5, :3 0, :1 9}}
```

removing the println is a good idea because with a list of 100 vertexes that for expression (it's not a loop in the sense that word has in other languages) is going to run 1 million times (100 * 100 * 100), so printing it out will take a while.

and because i'm a sucker for bonus points: here it is using reduce:

```
user> (def min-dist {:1 {:1 0 :2 4} :2 {:1 4 :2 0 :3 5} :3 {:2 5 :3 0}})
#'user/min-dist
user> (time
       (->> (for [k vertexes i vertexes j vertexes]     ;; start by making a sequence of all the combinatioins of indexes
              [i j k])
            (reduce
             (fn [result [i j k]]                       ;; the reducer function takes the result so far and either modifies it 
               (let [s (+ (get-in result [i k] inf)     ;; or passes it through unchanged.
                          (get-in result [k j] inf))]
                 (if (> (get-in result [i j] inf) s)    ;; depending on this if expression here.
                   (assoc-in result [i j] s)            ;; pass on the changed value
                   result)))                            ;; pass on the original value, unchanged
             min-dist)))                                ;; this argument is the initial value.
                                                        ;; the ->> expression places the result of the for expression here. (as the last argument)
"Elapsed time: 5.099 msecs"
{:1 {:1 0, :2 4, :3 9}, :2 {:1 4, :2 0, :3 5}, :3 {:2 5, :3 0, :1 9}}
```

This leaves the original value in min-dist intact.

Comment: For a 30% boost, consider using `x/for` https://gist.github.com/cgrand/3e055b80bf2d81c4ac25 ;-)

Comment: @cgrand I am usually happy to upvote your insightful answers/comments, but how is that on-topic for this question or answer? I'm sure your xfor is great, but nobody is asking how to make a for-comprehension faster.

Comment: I'm always mesmerized by the quality of the answers in the Clojure community.

Comment: @ArthurU Just one more question, I promise. =) When running the code with `dorun`, the nREPL prints `nil` a lot of times (I want to say 1 Million, but I didn't count it). Is it the return value for `swap!` or `if`?

Comment: If you had the dorun inside the for, it could have some similar effect though it's hard to say for sure without the code to see. `(for [...] (dorun ...))` rather than `(dorun (for ...))` though this is purely a guess, as it would result in a result that is a sequence of one million nils. try wrapping your code in a call to (take 10 ...) and just look at the first few results to see if thats the problem. The result of an if expression ("return value") is the result of whichever expression the conditional pointed at, and the result of swap! is the new value that was stored into the atom.

Comment: @amalloy ok it was awkward to plug my lib and bury the reason: when it comes to general memory efficiency for-comprehensions put a lot of pressure on the GC. Using transducers allow to get rid of some/most of the pressure.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt `(dorun (for ...))` is the same as `(doseq ...)`; I don't think you ever want to write the former.

Comment: Yes, @amalloy I agree. This only use of writing it out is for explaining the lazy bug. It should now otherwise be written this way.